# Doesn't dirt get into critical Starship parts?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship

I guess that once Starship prototypes are complete they should be pretty weather- and dirt-proof. They should be perfectly sealed and stainless steel is well-suited to life outside (though sometimes I wonder about the tough conditions by the sea in Boca Chica - there must be parts or equipment that rust and get full of wind-blown grit ... anyway ...)

But the parts are stored outside, final joins take place in buildings without doors and those workers climbing in and out of the hatches don't look particularly clean.

How does SpaceX avoid problems with dirt, grit and sea salt getting drawn into valves and engines?

Comment: My guess is the Soviet approach. Looser tolerances, more surplus force, tougher, thicker parts. If it can't withstand open hangar in Boca Chica, it won't withstand field servicing on Mars.

Comment: Rather obviously, those subassemblies which require cleanliness are sealed before integration. Those parts exposed to the environment are built to withstand dirt and chemical action

Comment: Carl, I'm sure that engines, valves and other critical parts are sealed until integration. But the tanks spend a lot of time outdoors and are completed in open buildings. Particles in the tanks must surely end up in the engines. If that's the case it's impressive that Starship can deal with this. I'm curious how SpaceX manages it.

Comment: @CharlieEvans They'd absolutely have to clean out/purge the tanks after final assembly. Many rocket engines have been destroyed by things like a single loose metal washer left in a propellant tank.

Comment: Propellant lines can have screens/filters in them. Sat through many meeting about whether it was worth going after a fleck of something on the screens.

Comment: @RussellBorogove - that makes a lot of sense! Perhaps the tests that take place before the first static fire on each prototype double as purges.
Do they all do an ambient leak test, cryo test and thrust-simulation test?
And do all three take place without the engines installed? With the engines off contaminants could be washed away safely.

Comment: That's interesting @OrganicMarble. How fine can the mesh be on those screens? I imagine that it would be difficult to operate with fine screens under such high-pressure, high-flow conditions. Fine enough to block sand?

Comment: They were 1000 micron screens on the shuttle https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20080031529/downloads/20080031529.pdf?attachment=true

Comment: @Organic Marble - great find :D

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies! I'm new to this sort of platform so I don't know how to conclude a discussion like this. But I've really enjoyed it and I'll be back!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that nobody outside of SpaceX knows. However I imagine that those parts which need to be kept really clean (like the Raptors) are built inside in clean conditions.

They may wash the tanks out with liquid nitrogen before connecting Raptors, they might use security filters on the tank outlets and equipment might be designed to be rugged enough to cope with small quantities of impurities.

Or it might be a source of some of their engine issues (although I doubt that very much).

Comment: This is a guess, not an answer.

Comment: Nobody outside of SpaceX knows. That is the truth of the matter as I said so all answers are going to be guesses unless Elon Musk turns up here and gives us chapter and verse on how they do it.

Comment: Protip: If you do not know the answer, do not write an answer.